# How to translate "Gern auch möbliert"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does that mean "Furnished apartment is highly appreciated"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give us some detail to work with: 1) Do you have problem understanding the German phrase or finding an English translation? 2) What have you already understood? Why did a dictionary not help you? 3) What is the context? (Yes, we can guess, but we do not want to.) 4) What do you need this translation for?

Comment: I have problem understanding the phrase. I know each words separately, but i just don't understand the phrase. It's from the passage in a german textbook.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to state that you are aiming to understand, describe how you understood the terms separately and what the textbook context is. We do not like to provide blunt translations but help you understand. And for this we need to know where to begin.

Comment: Where do you get the "higly" from?

Comment: We received a notice that multiple of your questions did not meet requirements for this site. Please take time to read the [tour] and get familiar with our standards. The system will otherwise automatically [ban your account from asking](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), a thing we all don't want. Thank you.

Comment: There are two interesting things in this question:
The expression "Gern auch" is vernacular German. It's unlikely you will find that in a dictionary. While specialized websites provide the answer (http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=gern%20auch), it seems to me to be of general interest.
The second thing is the particular redaction of German classifieds, which seems specific enough to be the subject of some question. If someone wants to rewrite this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the core of it:

This phrase is used by people who are looking for a place to rent, say a room in a flat sharing, or a small apartment or so, typically students, or people who start working in another city and need a quick solution for living. They use this sentence in order to clarify that they would accept both an empty room (or appartment) and one that has furniture.

It is not to indicate a preference. It indicates that both is acceptable.